# Quick Question on a Proof of Artin-Wedderburn Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, intuition

> **Question [Edited]:** [See below.] Are the isomorphisms in $(1)$ and $(2)$ *(additive) group homomorphisms*?
>
> If I'm right, $\text{End}_R(M)$ is a *ring*, but $\text{Hom}_R\left(M_i^{n_i},M_j^{n_j}\right)$ is only a *group* (we can't compose two functions in it). However when coming back to the direct sum of $\text{End}_R\left(M_i^{n_i}\right)$ we get a *ring* again.
>
> So, are we showing $\text{End}_R(M)\cong\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i=1}^k\text{End}_R\left(M_i^{n_i}\right)$ as *rings* by getting intermediate *group* isomorphisms?...
>
> **Also**, where is the hypothesis "finite type" used in the proof? [**Edit:** This has been answered in the comments.]

**Artin-Wedderburn Theorem:** Let $M$ be a semisimple $R$-module of finite type. Then $$\text{End}_R(M)\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^k M_{n_i\times n_i}(D_i)$$ for some division rings $D_i$.

**Proof:** $M=\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i=1}^k (M_i)^{n_i}$ where $M_i$ is simple.
\begin{align}
\text{End}_R(M)&=\text{End}_R\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^k(M_i)^{n_i}\right)\\
&\cong\bigoplus_{1\leq i,j\leq k}\text{Hom}_R\left(M_i^{n_i},M_j^{n_j}\right)\tag{1}\\
&\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^k\text{End}_R\left(M_i^{n_i}\right)\tag{2}\\
&\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^kM_{n_i\times n_i}\left(\text{End}_R(M_i)\right)\tag{3}\\
\end{align}
where $(2)$ is a consequence of Schur's Lemma and $(3)$ follows from a previous result.

$M_i$ simple $\stackrel{\text{Schur}}{\implies}$ $\text{End}_R(M_i)$ is a division ring.

All in all,
$$
\text{End}_R(M)\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^kM_{n_i\times n_i}(D_i)
$$
for some division rings $D_i$.$\blacksquare$

Comment: I think since $M$ is a module of finite type, or as is common to say that as $M$ is a f.g $R$ module, you can write $M$ as a direct sum of finitely many simple submodules. So the very first step of the proof outlined above seems to use that.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to something I asked long ago ( http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11576/apocryphal-maschke-theorem ). The intermediate isomorphisms (1) and (2) are a-priori just isomorphisms of additive groups, but if you look at the inverse isomorphism to their composition, you see that it just takes a list of endomorphisms of $M_i^{n_i}$ and combines them to an endomorphism of $\bigoplus_{i} M_i^{n_i}$; this is clearly a ring *homomorphism*, and thus an isomorphism because it is an inverse of a group isomorphism.

Comment: My comment was deleted since the answer I left it on was deleted. The isomorphism in (1) is akin to the block matrix decomposition of the endomorphism ring of a vector space given a direct sum decomposition of the vector space.

Comment: The individual summands in (1) don't have a ring structure, but the whole thing does: the multiplication is like matrix multiplication, as aes suggests above.  When you make (1) into a ring this way, the first $\cong$ will be an iso of rings. (1)$\cong$(2) is then just the statement that the off-diagonal entries in all these "matrices" are zero, so the second iso is also a ring iso where (2) is a direct sum of rings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds a bit like by "are they group isomorphisms" you are really asking "are they only group isomorphisms *and not ring isomorphisms?*" Of course they are additive group isomorphisms, but they are actually more than that.

While the individual Hom groups aren't rings, the sum $\bigoplus_{1\leq i,j\leq k}\text{Hom}_R\left(M_i^{n_i},M_j^{n_j}\right)$ *is* a ring!

Perhaps the way to get comfortable with it is to imagine it as a "formal" ring of matrices with entries from the Hom groups. Then formal matrix multiplication composes them in a reasonable way such it is a ring. The matrix multiplication matches the composition in $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ exactly through the map, so it *is* a ring homomorphism. This holds even if the $M_i$ lack their special properties (being pairwise nonisomorphic simple modules.)

In the passage from line (1) to (2), we simply eliminate a lot of superfluous terms in the direct sum and discover that the multiplication boils down to coordinatewise multiplication of a direct product of rings. That is what the pairwise nonisomorphic condition buys us.

So, the isomorphisms involved are ring isomorphism all the way through.

---

Here's another sort of example. Let $e$ be an idempotent in any ring with identity, and let $f=1-e$. Then one can show that $R\cong \begin{bmatrix}eRe&eRf\\fRe&fRf\end{bmatrix}$ as rings, where the multiplication on the right is formal matrix multiplication. Neither $eRf$ nor $fRe$ has to be a ring, but $eRe$ and $fRf$ are both rings.

You can look upon this as $R\cong\mathrm{End}_R(R)\cong \mathrm{End}_R(eR\oplus fR)=\mathrm{Hom}_R(eR\oplus fR,eR\oplus fR)\cong\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm{Hom}_R(eR,eR)&\mathrm{Hom}_R(fR,eR)\\\mathrm{Hom}_R(eR,fR)&\mathrm{Hom}_R(fR,fR)\end{bmatrix}$

The (group) isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_R(fR,eR)\cong eRf$ can be found in Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings* (Proposition 21.6.) It turns out to be a ring isomorphism if $e=f$.